# R How to filter data frame with macro variable name and number like SAS let

Tags: r, paste

I need to filter data1(data frame) based on Ave_redemption_hours less than 10. Below code works

```
data2 <- data1[data1$Avg_redemption_hours < 10,]
```

---

I want to assign a value to num and var, and using these to fileter data1, but data2 return no values.

```
num=10
var = quote(Avg_redemption_hours)
data2=data1[noquote(paste('data1',var,sep="$")) >num ,]
```

Does anyone know what the issue here and how to resolve this?

Best regards,

Ken

Comment: using data[,'var'] instead of  data$var

Comment: The relevant help page is `help("$")`.

Comment: Though not an exact duplicate, the core problem in the linked post is identical and the accepted answer therein will solve your problem.

Comment: Wen - data[,'var' < num ] didn't work for me. It retuned 0 variables in my data.